# Ionic 2 / 3: Number Input from Alert

Tags: arrays, typescript, input, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3.x on macOS.

I have the following issue:

I have an array containing a number and an array of names.

```
table: { number: number, names: string[] } = {
    number: 0,
    names: ['']
  };
```

I want to set the number of the array using an input for the user. I stumbled upon the AlertController.

I have written the following function thing to add a number:

```
addTable(){

    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Add Table',
      subTitle: 'Enter the table number',
      inputs: [{
        name: 'tableNumber',
        placeholder: 'Number',
        type: 'number'
      }],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Add',
          handler: data => {
            //this.tables.push(data);
            this.table.number = data;
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    prompt.present();

  }
```

But this always sets table.number to object [object]. If I write it as this.table.number = +data; it has the value NaN. The push version also doesn't work.

How do I set table.number to a number that the user put in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the input

```
name: 'tableNumber'
```

gets added as a property name to the resulting object. You can access it like this:

```
handler: data => {
    this.table.number = data.tableNumber;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Thank you for the fast answer :)

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to upvote if you found this answer useful.

Comment: The system did it automatically, sorry. I only know earned more than 15 rep. Before that, one isn't allowed to up vote, so the system took away my vote. Now it will stay :) Thank you again!